Reference request: A prevariety over $\mathbb{C}$ is separated iff its associated complex analytic variety is Hausdorff.

Let $X$ be a prevariety over $\mathbb{C}$. Then $X$ is separated iff its associated complex analytic variety $X^{an}$ is Hausdorff.

This problem is from my algebraic geometry lecture, which was one of the topics of the final projects. I want to prove this result as my final project, but I can't find any proof, even similar arguments. Hope for any references. Thanks!
If one doesn't know this result, it's welcome to give any idea about the topic of projects (about variety). I have thought about Bezout's theorem, but it needs too much background.

This certainly sounds plausible, and I think the "only if" direction is clear. But the "if" direction seems to require some kind of result to the effect that the image of a sufficiently nice monomorphism is closed in the Zariski topology if and only if it is closed in the analytic topology...

A possible reference is SGA1.XII.3.
Here's a rough outline of the argument.
One can show a relative version of the statement in question, namely if $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of $\Bbb C$-schemes locally of finite type, then $f$ is separated if and only $f^{an}$ is separated.
This in turn follows from the fact that in the same situation as above $f$ is a closed immersion if and only if $f^{an}$ is a closed immersion, as analytification plays nicely with fiber products and $X\to Y$ is separated if and only if the diagonal $X \to X \times_Y X$ is a closed immersion. (In either category.)
Now a closed immersion of schemes is exactly a proper monomorphism, so the idea is to show that $f$ is a monomorphism if and only $f^{an}$ (which is easy, using the characterisation of monomorphisms as those morphisms whose diagonal is an isomorphism) and the analogous statement for proper morphisms. This statement about properness is not so easy, we need to use Chow's lemma. I'll leave the details to Grothendieck.
